# Magento 2 Delta Migration : Delta Delivering Failed Give Error

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.3, delta-migration

When we perform delta migration then give the following error. For more information check the below screenshot.

> [ERROR]: Deltalog for catalog_category_entity is not installed

[image]